# Name automatically an alt tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this script how do I add an `alt` tag which value will be the same as "NikeAir 32" in this example?

```
<script> 
  function test_options_rendered(){
    $('.test_option_value').each(function(){            
      if( !$(this).parent().hasClass("conditional")){
        $(this).find('input:radio').first().prop("checked", true);
        // $(".test_radio_option :input:first").prop("checked", true);
      }
    });
    $('.test_radio_option:contains("Nike Air32")').append('<img class="option_img" src="https://image.png">');
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Your question and source made no sence for me. What have you tried to do?

Comment: you would do `$('.test_radio_option:contains("Nike Air32")').append('<img     class="option_img" alt="Nike Air32" src="https://image.png">');`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is add an `alt` tag to the `img` you can do it like this:

```
$('.test_radio_option:contains("Nike Air32")')
   .append('<img class="option_img" alt="Nike Air32" src="https://image.png">')
```

If you want to do it more dynamically you can do this:

```
$('.test_radio_option:contains("Nike Air32")').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<img class="option_img" alt="' + $(this).text() + '" src="https://image.png">');
});
```